# Generating an email based on mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I have 2 tables, displayed below.

LIKEPROFILE:

```
+------------+---------------+
|   user     |  ilike        |
+------------+---------------+
| testuser3  | testuser4     |
| testuser4  | testuser3     |
| testuser2  | testuser3     |
| testuser8  | testuser1     |
| testuser2  | testuser6     |
+------------+---------------+
```

I have a MYSQL table that updates when a user likes someone's profile in my website, shown above. I would like to create a php script that generates an an email when two users like one other.

For example, testuser3 likes testuser4 in the table above (row 1).  When testuser4 likes testuser3 (row 2), an an email should be generated to testuser3 and testuser4, telling testuser3 that testuser4 likes them and telling testuser4 that testuser3 likes them. Assume that testuser3 and testuser4 are email addresses (so usernames will actually be email addresses).

Thanks for your help!

Comment: When you insert a row into the table, lookup to see whether the opposing entry exists; if so, send an email.  What's the problem?

Comment: Sorry, since I am very new to php and this is my first project, I don't know how to send an email.

Comment: One way would be to use PHP's [`mail()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php) function.